# QT ofstream use variable as a path name

Tags: c++, qt, function, variables, ofstream

I'm trying to make a function which takes QString as well as an int.
Convert QString variable into a filename for ofstream, then take the integer and place it into the file. So far I have managed to take a constant filename such as "Filename.dat" and write a variable into it. However when I try to use QString like this :

```
void write(const char what,int a){
    std::ofstream writefile;
    writefile.open("bin\\" + what);
    writefile << a;
    writefile.close();
}
```

I get an error

```
void write(const char,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'const char
```

This is the function which calls write();

```
void Server::on_dial_valueChanged(int value)
{
    write("dial.dat",value);
}
```

When I use "bin\dial.dat" instead of combining "bin\" with a string it works fine. ofstream.open(); uses "const char*".

I've tried all the filetypes so they may not match my description

**The question is-**
Does anybody have an idea how to combine "bin\" and a QString and make it work with ofstream? 
I've spend a lot of time googling it but still can't make it work.
Thanks!
Any suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: This `"bin\\" + what` will not do what you thing its doing. It's not string connection.

Comment: Well.. In this case do you know how to connect those two strings and make them work with ofstream? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void write(const char what,int a)` is wrong as you pass only one char to function you should have `void write(const char* what,int a)` to pass pointer to cstring beginning.

You also want to concat two cstrings and in c++ you can't do it like in other languages but you can use std::string to do what you want.

Try this

```
#include <string>

void write(const char* what,int a){
    std::ofstream writefile;
    std::string fileName("bin\\");
    fileName+=what;
    writefile.open(fileName.c_str());
    writefile << a;
    writefile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just like I wanted it to. Managed to modify it a little bit and add an extra string with file type. Looks like not the variable type was the issue.

Comment: Btw. you are asking about QStrings and you don't use them in your code. And if you like my answer please also up vote ;)

Comment: I did ask, I've been learning cpp for the past month, now I'm trying my best with QT and so far I'm failing hard. Appreciate your help a lot